# Rewrite URL with suds Client

Tags: soap, wsdl, suds

We use suds to access a soap service.

```
url = 'https://example.com/scr-webservices/soap/AuthenticationService?wsdl'
client = Client(url)
client.login()
```

The result:

```
  File ".../suds/client.py", line 112, in __init__
    self.wsdl = reader.open(url)
  File ".../suds/reader.py", line 157, in open
    d = self.fn(url, self.options)
  File ".../suds/wsdl.py", line 159, in __init__
    self.build_schema()
  File ".../suds/wsdl.py", line 220, in build_schema
    self.schema = container.load(self.options)
  File ".../suds/xsd/schema.py", line 93, in load
    child.open_imports(options)
  File ".../suds/xsd/schema.py", line 305, in open_imports
    imported = imp.open(options)
  File ".../suds/xsd/sxbasic.py", line 542, in open
    result = self.download(options)
  File ".../suds/xsd/sxbasic.py", line 560, in download
    d = reader.open(url)
  File ".../suds/reader.py", line 84, in open
    d = self.download(url)
  File ".../suds/reader.py", line 100, in download
    fp = self.options.transport.open(Request(url))
  File ".../suds/transport/https.py", line 60, in open
    return  HttpTransport.open(self, request)
  File ".../suds/transport/http.py", line 105, in open
    fp = self.invoke(request, retfile=True)
  File ".../suds/transport/http.py", line 153, in invoke
    u2response = urlopener.open(u2request, timeout=tm)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 429, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 447, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 407, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1228, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1201, in do_open
    r = h.getresponse(buffering=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1136, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 453, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 417, in _read_status
    raise BadStatusLine(line)
httplib.BadStatusLine: ''
client.service.login()
```

If I debug into it, and think that this happens:

1. the url which I provide in `Client(url)` gets fetched by suds client library
2. suds parses the result. It discover other wsdl locations in the first wsdl
3. suds wants to fetch the other wsdl files by accessing the URLs which where found in the first wsdl.
4. These URLs are broken. They contain the wrong protocol: http instead of https.
5. suds tries to talk http to the https server
6. the https server stops the communication
7. at client side I see: BadStatusLine

But how to work around this? I have only access to the client. That's why I ask for a "work around" not for a solution :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a very dirty solution.

I am replacing urllib2.OpenerDirector.open() method temporarily.

This way I can fix the broken URLs which are in the wsdl which I receive. I change the URLs from "http" to "https".

Better solutions are more than welcome :-)

The first solution was to provide an alternative transport object. But not all client-server http connections seem to use this transport.

```
url = 'https://localhost:40443/scr-webservices/soap/AuthenticationService?wsdl'

import ssl

import mock
from suds.client import Client
from urllib2 import OpenerDirector


def rewrite_url(url):
    magic = 'http:'
    if magic in url:
        url = url.replace(magic, 'https:')
    return url


def my_open_director_open(original):
    def my_open(self, request_obj, **kwargs):
        request_obj.host = request_obj.get_host()
        request_obj._Request__original = rewrite_url(request_obj._Request__original)
        request_obj.type = 'https'
        return original(self, request_obj, **kwargs)

    return my_open


with mock.patch('ssl._create_default_https_context', ssl._create_unverified_context):
    opener_director_open_original = OpenerDirector.open
    try:
        OpenerDirector.open = my_open_director_open(opener_director_open_original)
        client = Client(url)
        print(client)
        print(client.service.remote_procedure_to_call())
    finally:
        OpenerDirector.open = opener_director_open_original
```